# Object won't detect collision by looking for a certain object's name in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a **2D** game in Unity, and my current script is pretty simple. The objective of the game is to maneuver an object (player) through obstacles (`leftObstacle` and `rightObstacle`), but my problem is that whenever the player gets hit by an obstacle, which it detects by looking for the `GameObject`'s name, nothing happens.

I've reread my code many times to look for wrong object references in the script, but also in the inspector, and I couldn't find any real mistakes. All of the objects also have an attached rigid body.

Here's the excerpt of the player script, where everything seems to be well referenced:

```
public class playerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    float playerPositionX;
    float playerSpeed;
    public bool playerEliminated;
    public GameObject leftObstacle;
    public GameObject rightObstacle;
    public GameObject Player;
```

Here's the excerpt of the left obstacle's script, where it needs to be looking for a collision:

```
public class obstacleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    float y;
    public GameObject Player;
    public GameObject leftObstacle;
    public GameObject rightObstacle;
    double currentHeightY;
    public float leftObstacleX;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Player")
        {
            Debug.Log("collision");
        }
    }
```

I'm not including the excerpt of the right obstacle's script, since the code there is pretty much the same as the left obstacle.

Pictures of the player object in the inspector:

[image: Picture of the player object in the inspector(1/2)]

[image: Picture of the player object in the inspector(2/2)]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the game objects name? And maybe it’s rigidbody/collider settings. Have you debugged what it does collide with?

Comment: I posted two pictures of the player gameobject's inspector page.  And the object it collides with (player), isn't stuck on any error, so I can't debug it

Comment: Does the OnCollisionEnter2D method even trigger or is only the name comparison failing?

Comment: I just checked it by adding a Debug.Log in the OnCollisionEnter2D method and it doesn't seem to be working, so I think the whole method is failing.

Comment: It should be Collider2D not collision2d as the parameter type in your scripts

Comment: I just changed it, but it gives me the "This message parameter has to be of type: Collision2D" error, so it doesn't work.

Comment: nvm, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the "Player" GameObject in the inspector or on a start method, why can't you do something like this?

```
float y;
public GameObject Player;
public GameObject leftObstacle;
public GameObject rightObstacle;
double currentHeightY;
public float leftObstacleX;

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {
    if(col.gameObject == Player)
    {
        Debug.Log("Collided with the Player");
    }
}
```

You could also change your if statment to

```
if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
{
    Debug.Log("Collided with the Player");
}
```

And then in the inspector go Tag, add a tag call it Player and attach the new tag to your player.